# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA to skip blank rows

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, nested-if, ifs

How to make my ARRAYFORMULA(A1 + something else) to stop producing results after there are no more values in A1 column, eg. to skip blank values. By default it gives endlessly "something else".

Here is my demo sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AikL5xRMB94BKwG34Z_tEEiI07aUAmlbNzxGZF2VeYs/edit?usp=sharing

Actual data in column A1 is regularly changing, rows are being added.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample sheet with sample data so that we can see what we are working on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="";;A1:A+1000))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried the others and they didn't work. This does though:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(filter(A1:B;A1:A<>"";B1:B<>""))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),"",(A1:A + B1:B)))` if this works out for you.

[image]

Reference:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en